# How To Find Out Which Package That Asset Belongs To?

Tags: unity

I have just messed up my project with some conflicting plugins, so i need to clean all plugins and reimport them, but i can't make sure which files to delete.

So how can i find out which package an asset belongs to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Do like reimporting the package, but stop at the last step. It will list you all the files which get imported by the package; clean this files manually. 
Unfortunately I do not know a way to unimport Unity packages.</s>

Well, after some reasearch I could find [this](http://movinarc.com/) package. I do not know if this plugin rewrites old (Standard Asset) data etc., but it is definitely worth a shot!

Advice for the future: If it is an important / time-intensive project add source control to your project! SVN works great if you are a part of a small team or no team at all. It is easy to Setup.
I can recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/index.de.html) as client, and [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) as server (for windows). Do not forget to exclude the library folder ;)